# Doctrine ManyToMany unique third entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have 2 table Song and Album. and I have created third entity SongAlbum with extra fields like it was described [here](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/collections/many-to-many-extra-fields).

Question: how to make sure that this third entity is unique by song and album. Example: there can't be another SongAlbum object with exactly same pair of song and album ids.

Comment: Have you tried it as [described in the Doctrine doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html)?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
/**
* Class SongAlbum
* @ORM\Table(name="song_album", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="song_album_unique", columns={"song", "album"})})
*/
```